# Python 3 uwsgi.opt return as str not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi 2 with Python 3.7 and have a problem with **uwsgi.opt** that returns all values as bytes type

Is there a config I can use to have all decoded into str?
Otherwise a solution is to decode them separately.